# JSDoc @typedef not being used in other files

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

In my file `lib/server.js` I have the following code:

```
/**
 * My Test Server
 * 
 * @typedef  {Object}   My.Server
 * @prop     {String}   name
 */
function Server() {
    this.name = 'zever';
}
```

When I reference this `@typedef` in the same file, it works:

[image: piece of code showing intelliSense is using the typedef in the same file]

However, when I use the `@typedef` in another file in the same project, I get nothing:

[image: type is not working in another file in the same project]

(And yes, I tried the jsdoc on a single line, too)

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "import" a typedef from one file to another in JSDoc using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836644/how-to-import-a-typedef-from-one-file-to-another-in-jsdoc-using-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52847569/1554499 .

You need to import your definition in the other file:

```
 /**
 @typedef {import('./my-new-type').MyNewType} MyNewType
 * */
```