# JSDoc typedef declaration for moment.js object

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, momentjs, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a function that uses `moment.js`.  I am new to typescript and jsdoc imports and I'm wondering how I can document that a function returns, specifically a moment object:

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
/**
 * @typedef Moment
 * @property {import('moment-timezone').Moment} moment
 */

/**
 * Returns a moment object with the date / time converted to the given timezone
 * @param {Date} dateTime
 * @param {string} targetTimeZone
 * @return {Moment} 
 */
const convertDateTimeToLocationTimeZone = (dateTime, targetTimeZone) => {
    return moment(dateTime).tz(targetTimeZone);
};
```

I'm not even sure if the above is totally off - but also the above gives me this error in vscode:

> Property 'moment' is missing in type 'import("/Users/Deb/Desktop/project/node_modules/moment/....").Moment' but required in type 'import("/Users/Deb/Desktop/project/...").Moment'.

Note, I do have `@types/moment-timezone` installed.

Comment: What happens if you change the `typedef` line to this:
`@typedef {import('moment-timezone').Moment} Moment
`? ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52847569/3015595))

Comment: No way! Hooray! I'll post it as a formal answer so that others will may benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost have it. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836644/how-to-import-a-typedef-from-one-file-to-another-in-jsdoc-using-node-js/52847569#52847569) to a similar question, I think you need to modify your code to match this:

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
/**
 * @typedef {import('moment-timezone').Moment} Moment
 */

/**
 * Returns a moment object with the date / time converted to the given timezone
 * @param {Date} dateTime
 * @param {string} targetTimeZone
 * @return {Moment} 
 */
const convertDateTimeToLocationTimeZone = (dateTime, targetTimeZone) => {
    return moment(dateTime).tz(targetTimeZone);
};
```

Hope that works!