# How can I make a VS Code reference from one class to another class file while it is injected through a constructor?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have three files:

- index.js
- employee.js
- employer.js

index.js

```
import Employer from "./employer.js"
import Employee from "./employee.js"

const employer = new Employer();
const employee = new Employee(employer);
```

employee.js

```
class Employee {
  constructor(employer) {
    this.employer = employer;
  }

  getEmployer() {
    return this.employer.name();
  }
}
```

employer.js

```
class Employer() {
  name() {
   return "Default Employer";  
  }
}
```

The problem here in VS code is that if I `CTRL + Click` on the `employer.name()` it does not navigate to `employer.js` file since it is not referenced via "import" but passed via constructor parameter. Since I am in a vanilla JS environment, is there a way to tell VS Code that `employer` is an instance of “Employer” class and make it navigate when I click on it?

Comment: add JSDOC to the constructor to tell it the types of the parameters, you will have to import the Employer class

Comment: @rioV8 this seems like a legit solution. Although that will generate linter error of not used import. Any way to avoid this? Like soft referencing to the file?

Comment: why does the `Employer` have a name, but the `Employee` not

Comment: where does the employer name even come from? You don't pass one in the constructor call.

Comment: This is just a demonstration. Real files are totally different, but conceptually I am having the same problem. @rioV8

Comment: then learn the linter to read JSDOC, you use the name property, so you need to have the `Employer` class to have the linter happy, it must know that `this.employer` has a `name` property, it should complain about that if not imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/), but it requires you to turn your employer.js into a ES6 module:

employer.js example:

```
export class Employer() {
  name() {
    return "Default Employer";  
  }
}
```

employee.js:

```
class Employee {
  /** @param {import("./employer").Employer} employer */
  constructor(employer) {
    this.employer = employer;
  }
  ...
}
```

The `import()` syntax is [dynamic import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), which TypeScript supports type support for.

If you don't want to have to turn employer.js into a ES6 module, see https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1645 (also related: [How to "import" a typedef from one file to another in JSDoc using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49836644/11107541))

Comment: That import syntax is the one I am looking for. T.hanks!